# Busqueda simple con formulario PHP

Tags: php

Estoy teniendo un problema, estoy haciendo una **web scraping** de otra, por ejemplo:

Este es mi archivo que hace la busqueda: `busqueda.php?url=https://webdecocina.com/busqueda?q=` luego de `busqueda?q=` iria el texto de la busqueda, si lo pongo manualmente en el *link* funciona perfecto, pero por el formulario no se como pasarlo.

Yo tengo esto:

---

**busqueda.php**

```
$busqueda = $_POST["busqueda"]; 
$html =  file_get_html(htmlspecialchars($_GET["url"].$busqueda));
```

---

**inicio.php**

```
$busqueda=htmlspecialchars($_GET["busqueda"]);

<form action="busqueda.php?url=https://webdecocina.com/busqueda?q=" method="post"> 
busqueda: 
<input type="text" name="edad" size="2"> 
<input type="submit" value="Entrar"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Cuando mandas un formulario los datos se seriaiizan usando como clave las etiquetas `name`, por tanto en este caso el dato estaría en la clave `edad`, dado que tienes esto en el formulario: `name="edad"` otra cosa, el método es `POST`, por tanto usa lo mismo para recuperar el dato, por ejemplo: `$_POST["edad"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la URL siempre va a ser la misma no tiene sentido enviarla como parámetro y, de hecho, es recomendable que el formulario lo envíes usando método GET.

```
<?php
// Valor inicial (si es que lo hay)
$busqueda = (isset($_GET['busqueda'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['busqueda']) : '';
?>
<form action="busqueda.php" method="get">
Buscar:
<input type="text" name="busqueda" value="<?php echo $busqueda; ?>">
<inptu type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Luego, para procesar el formulario

```
<?php
$busqueda = (isset($_GET['busqueda'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['busqueda']) : '';
$url = 'https://webdecocina.com/busqueda?q=' . $busqueda;
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

**Nota:** La web parece no estar activa, con HTTPS no abre y con HTTP redirecciona a otro dominio.

Comment: Claro, si la url siempre será la misma no tiene sentido enviarla cada vez. Ahora por que es recomendable usar GET en vez de POST (me llamó la atención)

Comment: Es la forma en que funcionan los buscadores, te permiten agregar esas búsquedas a favoritos y no te pide reenviar el formulario cuando avanzas o retrocedes en el historial.

Comment: Gracias, parece funcionar. La web "webdecocina.com" era un ejemplo, para no poner las webs que estoy usando, porque capaz no está permitido.

Comment: si, puede ser, pero creo que profundizaste demasiado el problema, ya que depende que quiere hacer una vez "scrapee" el sitio web.

Comment: @jolsalazar, quizá tienes razón, suelo usar método POST solo para formularios que se van a procesar e ingresar/borrar información en base de datos, para todo lo demás uso GET.

Answer (score 0):

En ese caso lo podrías hacer así

Donde en el input `url` iria la url a buscar y en `q` iria el parámetro de búsqueda (que en tu caso al parecer es el valor de la edad) dentro de la url anterior.

```
<form action="busqueda.php" method="post"> 
busqueda: 
<input type="text" name="url" value="https://webdecocina.com/busqueda?q=">
<input type="text" name="q" value="2"> 
<input type="submit" value="Entrar"> 
</form>
```

y en busqueda.php

```
$url = $_POST["url"];
$q = $_POST["q"];

$urlConParametro = $url.$q;
$html =  file_get_html(htmlspecialchars($urlConParametro));
```

Comment: Que tal, estoy probando esto, y al buscar me sale asi: `Warning: file_get_contents(https://webdecocina.com/busqueda?q=milanesa): failed to open stream: No se puede establecer una conexi�n ya que el equipo de destino deneg� expresamente dicha conexi�n. in C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\qch\webapp\simple_html_dom.php on line 82`

Comment: Pero esto no tiene mucho sentido, llamar a otra URL dentro de un envío de formulario. Lo lógico sería hacer la búsqueda y devolver los datos. No entiendo qué sentido tiene ahí el parámetro `url` ¿?

Comment: Osea el sentido lo hace por que puede poner cualquier url para hacer esta evaluacion de algun sitio web para obtener los datos. Ya que PHP se encargará de procesar la URL pasada.

Comment: El error de file_get_contents puede deberse a varias opciones, aun asi no es parte de esta pregunta, menos de esta respuesta. Deberias revisar quizas la funcion no envia bien alguna cabecera requerida, etc.